# Javascript and multiple instances of a form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have an entity called product. There is a field called item price.

Now i have created 100 products. I want to SUM (mathematical operation) all the products "item price" field and display it in an other entity called opportunity field called "total items price".

Besides this if i create 101 product and it's "item price", "total items price" field in opportunity automatically up date itself.

So for i have SUMMED to fields of a form. e.g there is a field A and field B, multiplying field A with 3.14 and displaying result in field B.

Here is the Code.

```js
function SumField() {  
   var price = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_price");   
   var total_price = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_total_price");

   if(price.getValue() != null) {
      var newValue = price.getValue() * 3.14;
      total_price.setValue(newValue);

      // Make sure the changes are saved back to the server - in CRM 4.0, this was     crmForm.new_fieldname.ForceSubmit = true;
      Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_total_price").setSubmitMode("always"); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain better what you want? Do you want update the opportunity field?

Comment: yes i want the opportunity's field  update automatically.

Comment: The code you have shown would indicate you are adding up fields on a single form and are updating another field on that form. This seems at odds with your question - which suggests adding up values across several entities and then updating a further different entity. Can you explain the significance/relevance of the code? Are you using it?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript will not work in this scenario, atleast it will not be the most optimum solution.

Rather than handling it with JavaScript write a Plugin that fires on change in Product entity and updates the desired record of opportunity entity. (I am considering that there will be few products related to one opportunity i.e. 1:N relationship)

In case you want that change in one product will update values in all records Opportunity create a another entity say "Configuration" which will hold this value and show it on Opportunity form using JavaScript (reason being: If one product record creation updates all records of Opportunities it will impact performance of CRM)

Answer (score 1):

You have some possibilities, the best choice depends of your technology expertise:

- Workflow - launch workflow when the field new_total_price changed and update the opportunity related. For this you don't need any known of programming languages
- Plugin - in update of your product entity you can update the related opportunity. You need know C# or VB .NET
- Javascript - One solution is onload of opportunity you check if product related has (you case use FetchXML or OData for example) the new_total_price filled, with that information you can update your opportunity.

There is more alternatives but you have here some options.

Comment: Is there any function (CRM SDK function) that can be used to iterate all the instances of a form to select a specific field.

Comment: No there is no way to get the instances of a form. What are your trying to do?